# KUSTO display two series of data

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have this query and the data display my graph and I have to select on the dropdown on graph chart data_in_Gbps and data_out_Gbps

However, I am interested in adding both data on the graph instead of currently I have to create 2 graphs. what needs to add to show both data on graph?

```
  Azure
 | where ResourceId contains "tedr"
 | where MetricName == "BitsInPerSecond"
 | where TimeGenerated > (now() - 300h) and TimeGenerated <= now()
 | project TimeGenerated, Resource, MaxInBps =Maximum
 | join kind= inner
  (
 Azure
  | where MetricName == "BitsOutPerSecond"
  | where TimeGenerated > (now() - 300h) and TimeGenerated <= now()
  | project TimeGenerated, Resource, MaxOutBps= Maximum
  )
  on TimeGenerated, Resource
  | summarize data_in_Gbps = max(MaxInBps)/100* 100, data_in_Gbps = max(MaxOutBps)/1000 * 100 by bin(TimeGenerated, 5m), Resource
```

Thanks!!

Comment: The question isn't clear. Please put here a screenshot of what you get, and provide an explanation of what you want to see differently.

Comment: thanks, I have added the screenshot. as I said I want to add 1:data_in_Gbps
2:data_out_Gbps on my chart.

Comment: According to the screenshot, you're in the Log Analytics blade. So the question should go to them, not to Kusto. Please remove Kusto tags and add Log Analytics tag instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 series are not supported when they are also have other dimensions, in your case by ResourceId. Removing the split by ResourceId by selecting Don't split will allow you to select multiple series

[image]